# Como eu coloco essa div vertical no canto superior esquerdo da tela?

Tags: html, html5

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Impressão de Carnê</title>
  <style>
    .vertical {
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      margin-top: 165px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">
    <div class='vertical'>
      <table border='1' borderColorLight='#000000' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p align="left">
              <font face="Verdana" size="2">Loja:</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p align="left">
              <font face="Verdana" size="2">Cliente:</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="left">
              <font face="Verdana" size="2">Contrato/OS:<br/>Vencimento:</font>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="left">
              <font face="Verdana" size="2">Parcela:<br/>Valor:</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p align="left">
              <font face="Verdana" size="2">Recebido Por:_____________________________<br/><br/>Data:________________ Hora:______________</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>




  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform-origin` para controlar o ponto de rotação da tabela em um dos vértices como eu fiz abaixo, no caso eu usei `transform-origin: top left;`.

O `transform-origen` *default* é `center`, por isso vc precisou usar o `margin-top`, mas agora é desnecessário e deixei ele comentado

```css
.vertical {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* margin-top: 165px; */
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div class='vertical'>
    <table border='1' borderColorLight='#000000' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p align="left">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Loja:</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p align="left">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Cliente:</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p align="left">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Contrato/OS:<br/>Vencimento:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p align="left">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Parcela:<br/>Valor:</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p align="left">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Recebido Por:_____________________________<br/><br/>Data:________________ Hora:______________</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação.